# Why does showing a OpenFileDialog in WPF block my WPF Popup?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a WPF application where i open a popup mennu (popup control) using the escape key. In that popup menu I open a file dialog when pushing a button, and the when pushing the button closes the popup. When i next time pushes the esc button it doesnt pop up, not until i have focused another program, eg. reset focus. Does anyone know what could cause this?

**Edit**

```
 //called when pushing esc
 private void ShowSettingsMenu()
 {
    SettingsMenu.IsOpen = true;
 }

//clicking my button, subsequent presses on my esc, doesnt pop it up (the code is run)
private void ImportLicenseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  SettingsMenu.IsOpen = false; //<- hiding it again

  OpenFileDialog filedialog = new OpenFileDialog();
  filedialog.Filter = "Xml Files|*.xml";
  if ((bool)filedialog.ShowDialog())
  {
      string fileName = "license.xml";
      string destinationFolder = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Directory.FullName;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filedialog.FileName))
      {
         File.Copy(filedialog.FileName, System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName), true);
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Please select a file name");
      }
   }
   this.Cursor = Cursors.None;
}
```

Comment: Code would help to diagnose...

Comment: is the key handler code also added to the popup itself? if not then the popup may still have focus (but be hidden) when the open file dialog returns, preventing the key stroke from registering with the window. Popups are rendered in seperate windows from their parent control, so events may not be routed in the same way. Try setting the Parent property of the popup if it is not automatically set.

Comment: One of the key things you do above, is hide the popup before displaying the dialog. Always catches people out as assumption is made that the dialog will have the highest z index in the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by redisplaying the popup.